# Why does running my R/Quarto website give me a lua 136 error

Tags: filter, lua

I developed my website with R/Quarto. It worked well. Now it gives me an error running Lua  (nr.136). I see more people have this problem. How to solve, what to do.

I don't know at all. Here you see what I got:
Error running Lua:
YAML parse exception at line 12, column 0:
did not find expected 
stack traceback:
...ntents/Resources/app/quarto/share/filters/qmd-reader.lua:136: in function 'Reader'